# Upper bound of a set

Tags: real-numbers, upper-lower-bounds

A non-empty subset $S ⊆  \mathbb{R}$ is bounded above by $k ∈ \mathbb{R}$ if
$s ≤ k$ for all $s ∈ S$. The number $k$ is called an upper bound for $S$.

Could by this definition we say that $S$ can have the greatest element and that element is the upper bound?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By that definition, *if* $S$ has a greatest element, *then* that element is an upper bound of $S$. That's the only case in which an element of $S$ is also an upper bound of $S$.

On the other hand, even if $S$ has no greatest element, it still can have upper bounds.